# Is $\mathbb{(Z_7\setminus \{0\},*)}\cong \mathbb{(Z_6,+)}?$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, modular-arithmetic

I want to prove or disprove that $\mathbb{(Z_7\setminus \{0\},*)}\cong\mathbb{(Z_6,+)}$. I thought of the possible isomorphism f:$\mathbb{(Z_7,*)}\to \mathbb{(Z_6,+)}$ with $\mathrm{f([3^{k}]_7)=[k]_6}$. Now for proving that it's well-defined, I did the following: suppose that $[3^{k}]_7=[3^{k'}]_7$ , then $3^k-3^{k'} \in \mathbb{7Z} $,$\ $, but now I' struggling to prove that f($[3^{k'}]_7$ )=f($[3^{k}]_7$). Any suggestions to prove or disprove this?

Comment: Personally I think the converse isomorphism $[n]_6 \mapsto [3^n]_7$ is easier to deal with. Hint: $3^6 = 729 = 728 + 1$.

Comment: Abelian groups of order 6 are cyclic

Comment: With the order so small, it might be easier just to write out the Cayley table, no? With the elements in the order $3^k = 3, 2, 6, 4, 5, 1$.